# Export all visible sheets to PDFs

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using below code to export all visible sheets to PDFs. It has worked fine for months for me and my colleagues, and still does on my computer. However, on 2 colleagues' computers, the

> runtime error -2147319767 (80028029)

started occurring recently.
I've seen similar threads mentioning this error but still don't see how to solve it in this case.

```
Sub ExportToPDFs()

Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In Worksheets

If ws.Visible = -1 Then
    ws.Select
    nm = ws.Name

    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:="D:\Test\" & nm & ".pdf", _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

End If
 
Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a "D:\Test\" path on computers raising the error?

Comment: @FaneDuru Thanks for the suggestion. The path exists on the computers, I tried changing it to another path that's also on there, but this didn't solve it.

Comment: When which code line that error is raised? And which is its description?

Comment: Do you know the version of excel they are using? I have had nasty experiences with excel 2013 (also with PDF export). Un explainable errors, out of memory (still loads of RAM available). Once the box was updated with Excel 2019, all was good..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Export Visible Worksheets to PDF

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ExportToPDFs()

    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    Const FolderPath As String = "C:\Test\T2022\72571395\"
    Const FileExtension As String = ".pdf" ' fixed; do not change
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    ' Alternatives:
    'Set wb = ActiveWorkbook ' workbook you're looking at
    'Set wb = Workbooks("Test.xlsx") ' a specific open workbook
    'Set wb = Workbooks.Open("D:\Test\Test.xlsx") ' a specific closed workbook

    ' Export worksheets.
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim FileCount As Long
    Dim ErrorFileCount As Long
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim MsgString As String
    Dim ErrorMsgString As String
    Dim AnExportErrorOccurred As Boolean
    
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        If ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
            FilePath = FolderPath & ws.Name & FileExtension
            On Error GoTo ExportError
                ws.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=FilePath, _
                    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
            On Error GoTo ClearError
            If AnExportErrorOccurred Then
                AnExportErrorOccurred = False
            Else
                MsgString = MsgString & vbLf & FilePath
                FileCount = FileCount + 1
            End If
        'Else ' not visible; do nothing
        End If
    Next ws
    
    ' Inform.
    
    Select Case FileCount
    Case 0
        MsgString = "No files exported."
    Case 1
        MsgString = "The following file was created:" & MsgString
    Case Else
        MsgString = "The following " & FileCount & " files were created:" _
            & MsgString
    End Select
    
    Select Case ErrorFileCount
    Case 0
        ' do nothing
    Case 1
        ErrorMsgString = "The following file was not created:" & ErrorMsgString
        If FileCount = 0 Then
            MsgString = ErrorMsgString
        Else
            MsgString = MsgString & vbLf & vbLf & ErrorMsgString
        End If
    Case Else
        ErrorMsgString = "The following " & ErrorFileCount _
            & " files were not created:" & ErrorMsgString
        If FileCount = 0 Then
            MsgString = ErrorMsgString
        Else
            MsgString = MsgString & vbLf & vbLf & ErrorMsgString
        End If
    End Select

    If FileCount = 0 Then
        If ErrorFileCount = 0 Then
            MsgBox MsgString, vbExclamation
        Else
            MsgBox MsgString, vbCritical
        End If
    Else
        If ErrorFileCount = 0 Then
            MsgBox MsgString, vbInformation
        Else
            MsgBox MsgString, vbCritical
        End If
    End If

ProcExit:
    Exit Sub

ExportError:
    Debug.Print "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "': " & Err.Description
    ErrorMsgString = vbLf & FilePath
    ErrorFileCount = ErrorFileCount + 1
    AnExportErrorOccurred = True
    Resume Next

ClearError:
    Debug.Print "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "': " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit

End Sub
```